# Best solution for a drop down list with over 300 rows?

Tags: html, jsf-2, accessibility, usability

I have this problem, in a form I have a list of customers that could be more than 300 and, for me, it isn't very simple find over there because I should scroll all results for find a single row!

On the old technology I had a button that opened a pop up where I should research which customer I should select and than I used a javascript for recording the selection on the first form, but It could be a good solution with new technology!

How can I resolve this doubt? What is the best solution for big `<select>` tag?

Comment: consider posting your question on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want an autocomplete dropdown list. This does not exist in the standard JSF component set and it is also not exactly trivial to implement with JavaScript/jQuery on top of the standard JSF component set because the available values have to be present in the server side's state. You also basically want a dropdown list which is represented by a `<div><input><ul><li>` instead of a `<select><option>` because a normal `<select>` doesn't allow the enduser to type text in. The standard JSF component set does not have a component which renders the desired HTML markup. You'd basically need to create a custom JSF component.

There are 3rd party JSF component libraries which already offer a fullworthy JSF autocomplete dropdown list. It would be easier to use either of them instead of reinventing the wheel by a custom JSF component. Take your pick:

- [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) - [the `<p:autoComplete>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml)
- [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces) - [the `<rich:autocomplete>` component](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&skin=blueSky)
- [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org) - [the `<o:suggestionField>` component](http://openfaces.org/demo/suggestionfield/SuggestionField.jsf)
- [ICEfaces](http://icefaces.org) - [the `<ice:selectInputText>` component](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)

Answer (score 3):

you can try jquery ajax autocomplete

Refer to:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Please note that the OP is as per the question tags using JSF, which is a stateful component based MVC framework. Implementing jQuery isn't exactly trivial as you have to take the server side state into account as well. You'd rather like to use a JSF component for this instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the jQuery autocomplete plugin is the best solution for you while you have a large number of items.

By the way, imagine that you would like to select an item with specific letters. While you are using drop down lists, you can point to your wanted items by typing their names from the first letter of each one. But using jQuery autocomplete, you can search a string or a group of letters in everywhere. it does not matter if are your inserted letters located at the first of your item names or in other places.

As ShantanuD said, you can find this plugin in http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/